Plotly: how do you color different y-ranges in the background?
I have the following plot:
import plotly 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1 = [ '2023-11-01','2023-11-02','2023-11-03','2023-11-04','2023-11-05',
       '2023-11-06','2023-11-07','2023-11-08','2023-11-09','2023-11-10' ]
y1 = [ 0.97, 0.70, 0.90,-1.52,-1.97,-0.18,-2.03,-0.07,-1.31, 0.75 ]
y2 = [-1.29,-1.12, 0.49,-0.13,-1.39, 0.79, 0.80, 0.53, 0.94, 0.10 ] 
y3 = [ 1.29, 0.12,-1.00, 1.13, 0.90,-1.22, 0.91, 1.53, 0.88,-0.17 ]
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1,mode='lines+markers', line_color='#8600ff',name='level 3'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y2,mode='lines+markers', line_color="#23c6cc",name='level 1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y3,mode='lines+markers', line_color="#3176e0",name='level 2'))
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True,xaxis=dict(tickfont=dict(size=14, color='black')),)
fig.update_yaxes(
    range=(-3, 3),
    color='green'
)
fig.update_layout(
                  yaxis = dict(
                    tickmode='array', #change 1
                    tickvals = [4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4], #change 2
                    ticktext = ['4.0','3.0','2.0','1.0','Mean','1.0','2.0','3.0','4.0'], #change 3
                    ))
fig.show()

The code produces the graph I'd like, except I'd like to be able to alter the background as follows:

The hex codes for these colors are as follows:
#eeeeee light purple
#f5f5f5 lighter purple

Can you show me how to modify the above graph so that its background looks like the image?

The image link seems to have broken, will recommend posting it directly here than using external link. And have you found a solution to this yet? (I'm curious, there's no clear cut documentation on achieving the task). If nothing yet, you can improve on my answer and that should get you to the desired output.

This is my best effort.
Approach
I considered finding a means to override or change the background properties, but the closest and most intuitive option I found was using shapes and Layout objects.
Since the ranges of y-axes we want to color are known statically, it's just a matter of carefully mapping the range to the dimensions of the rectangular shapes that will cover those positions in the background. What's left is to color the borders as desired.
This is what the code will look like. I had to adjust the colors a bit as I believe it comes closest to the screenshot you have, however, you can correct them as you wish.
import plotly.graph_objects as go

color_map = {
    (-3,-2): "#d9d9d9", # "rgb(192, 192, 192, 0.1)",     # Dark Grey
    (-2,-1): "#e6e6e6", # "rgb(229, 228, 226, 0.1)",     # Grey
    (-1,0): "#f5f5f5", # "rgba(211, 211, 211, 1.0)",     # Light Grey
    (0,1): "#f5f5f5", # "rgba(211, 211, 211, 1.0)",      # Light Grey
    (1,2): "#e6e6e6", # "rgb(229, 228, 226, 0.1)",       # Grey
    (2,3): "#d9d9d9" # "rgb(192, 192, 192, 0.1)",       # Dark Grey
}

# Purple tints
light_purple = "rgba(224, 176, 255, 0.6)"  #"#E0B0FF"
lighter_purple = "rgba(224, 176, 255, 0.2)" #"#D8BFD8"

x1 = [ '2023-11-01','2023-11-02','2023-11-03','2023-11-04','2023-11-05',
       '2023-11-06','2023-11-07','2023-11-08','2023-11-09','2023-11-10' ]
y1 = [ 0.97, 0.70, 0.90,-1.52,-1.97,-0.18,-2.03,-0.07,-1.31, 0.75 ]
y2 = [-1.29,-1.12, 0.49,-0.13,-1.39, 0.79, 0.80, 0.53, 0.94, 0.10 ]
y3 = [ 1.29, 0.12,-1.00, 1.13, 0.90,-1.22, 0.91, 1.53, 0.88,-0.17 ]

layout = go.Layout(
    shapes=[
        {
            'type': 'rect',
            'x0': '2023-10-31',   # Start from the leftmost edge
            'y0': y[0],
            'x1': '2023-11-11',   # End at the rightmost edge
            'y1': y[1],
            'fillcolor': color_map[y],
            'layer': 'above',
            'opacity': 0.4,
            'line': {'width': 3, 'color': light_purple if (y[0] >= 2 or y[0] <= -2) else lighter_purple}
        }
        for y in color_map.keys()
    ]
)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1,mode='lines+markers', line=dict(color='#8600ff'), name='level 3'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y2,mode='lines+markers', line=dict(color="#23c6cc"), name='level 1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y3,mode='lines+markers', line=dict(color="#3176e0"), name='level 2'))
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True,xaxis=dict(tickfont=dict(size=14, color='black')),)
fig.update_yaxes(
    range=(-3, 3),
    color='green'
)
fig.update_layout(
                  yaxis = dict(
                    tickmode='array', #change 1
                    tickvals = [4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4], #change 2
                    ticktext = ['4.0','3.0','2.0','1.0','Mean','1.0','2.0','3.0','4.0'], #change 3
                    ))

fig.update_layout(layout)  # The Layout shapes we added/colored

fig.show()


Output:
Before:

After:


That's pretty good for your best effort.  Thank you, M.A.
